# How to capture JSON request message

Tags: c#, json, async-await, task-parallel-library

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("customers/xxxx/xxxxx/documents", requestMessage);
```

requestMessage is a C# object representation of JSON. When using PostAsJsonAsync, I do not get the same response as posting a JSON string. I want to somehow intercept, may be write to log file or somewhere and check the JSON string that is being constructed for verification.

Please suggest.

Comment: What kind of object are you expecting? A HttpResponseMessage? If so, check response.Result, as the async methods returns Task<T> objects.

Comment: @fbiagi: I want the JSON payload as string to the POST request. My expected output could be {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}

Comment: well, i simply did this                         var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestMessage);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, its simply by using the serializeobject on JsonConvert

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestMessage);
```